# Redux - My reducers doesn't get called by my action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to call a Redux action but it fails. Other actions are well called without any problem. So I wonder what is going wrong.

*interestingly my broken redux function returns:*

```
ƒ displayDishAction(id) {
  return {
    type: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__actionTypes__["b" /* DISH_ID */],
    id: id
  };
}
```

***on a working function, it returns:***

```
ƒ () {
    return dispatch(actionCreator.apply(this, arguments));
  }
```

Here my reactComponent.js:

```
class Appetizers extends Component {

   /* props: 
        - bakground_url 
        - recipe_descrption
        - title
  */

  onClick= (id) => {  
    console.log("dish id: ", this.props.displayDish) 
    this.props.displayDish(id)
  }

  renderRecipes(){      
      return (           
      this.props.data.recipes.map(({id, picture, description, title, price}, index) => { 
          return ( 

            <div className={style.wrapper} onClick={() => this.onClick(id)}> 
              <DishBox 
              key={id}
              className={style.box_dish}
              title={title}
              description={description}
              picture={picture}
              price={price}
              id={id} 

              />
            </div>
          )
      })
  )}
```

My actions.js :

```
import { 
    DISH_ID
} from "../actionTypes"; 

export const displayDishAction= (id) => ({
        type: DISH_ID,
        id
})
```

My reducer.js:

```
import {
    DISH_ID
} from "../actionTypes"; 


var initialState ={id:""};

export const displayDishReducer= (state= initialState, action) => { 

    var id= action.id 

    console.log("DISPLAYDISHREDUCER REACHED !!!")
    switch(action.type){ 
        case DISH_ID : 
                var newState = Object.assign({}, state, id);
                return  newState;           
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

My actionType.js:

```
export const DISH_ID= "DISH_ID";
```

My container.js:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
{import components ...}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>({
    displayDish :displayDishAction
})
```

const appetizersContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Appetizers)
export default appetizersContainer

```
const myContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Appetizers)
export default myContainer
```

here my appReducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux"; 
import {displayDishReducer} from "./handleDisplayer"; 

// only one reducer active 
const appReducer = combineReducers({ 
    displayDishReducer
})
export default appReducer
```

here my store/index.js:

```
import {createStore, compose} from 'redux'


import appReducer from './reducers';
import middleware from './middleware'
// import {DevTools} from "../container/DevTools.jsx" ;

const enhancer = compose(
  middleware,
 // DevTools.instrument()
)


 export default (initialState) => {
  const store = createStore(appReducer, initialState, enhancer) ;
```

I can't figure out what is wrong, any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Is the `console.log` working?

Comment: thanks for answering, nope my console.log for the reducer reaching doesn't even works.. but I know my reducer is entered in the store because it appears in my initial state object

Comment: Please post your full component.

Comment: done my topic has been updated

Comment: I know my reactComponent receives the redux function because when I console log it the function appears

Comment: Did you pass your `reducer` to your `createStore` and did you add in a `Provider` for your store on your application?

Comment: yes it is passed through appReducer, the provider is passed in the app.layout, my layout wraps my component. The state of the app is well displayed on the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining your `mapDispatchToProps` function wrong. If you want to use the long version, I mean using with `dispatch`, then you should use it like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    displayDish: id => dispatch( displayDishAction( id ) ),
})
```

But, this shorthand works in your situation:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    displayDish: displayDishAction,
}
```

Even, without defining a `mapDispatchToProps` you can use `connect` like this:

```
const myContainer = connect(null, {displayDish: displayDishAction} )(Appetizers)
```